# Find shared lines among different files/lists using bash

Tags: list, share

I've got several lists like below:

LIST1

```
chr10   NM_000141
chr10   NM_000188
chr10   NM_000235
chr10   NM_000278
chr10   NM_000281
chr10   NM_000314
chr10   NM_000375
chr10   NM_000392
chr10   NM_000399
chr10   NM_000417
```

LIST2

```
chr10   NM_000235
chr10   NM_000278
chr10   NM_000281
chr10   NM_000314
chr10   NM_000392
chr10   NM_000399
chr10   NM_000609
chr10   NM_000681
chr10   NM_000684
chr10   NM_000698
```

LIST3

```
chr10   NM_000235
chr10   NM_000188
chr10   NM_000278
chr10   NM_000314
chr10   NM_000399
chr10   NM_000609
chr10   NM_000684
chr10   NM_000818
chr10   NM_000872
chr10   NM_000917
```

My question is, how to find the lines shared by all 3 lists using bash? (like here easy to observe that `chr10 NM_000235` is the shared by all three)
thx

Answer (score 1):

use the comm command

```
$ comm /path/to/file1/ /path/to/file2
$ comm -1 /path/to/file1/ /path/to/file2
$ comm -2 /path/to/file1/ /path/to/file2
$ comm -3 /path/to/file1/ /path/to/file2
```

where

```
-1 : suppress lines unique to FILE1
-2 : suppress lines unique to FILE2
-3 : suppress lines that appear in both files
```

compare two files first and keep the result in a "temp". (if "temp" is empty then no need to compare with the 3rd file). Then compare temp with the third file.

I am also providing a link to a short tutorial [here](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/08/linux-comm-command-brief-tutorial.html).